# bash command error

Tags: linux, bash

```
i=0
while read line

    do
    echo "i is --- $i"
    #echo $line "\n"

    if (( $i > 0 ))
    then
    $Eda_package=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
    $well_bias=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
    $biasmap=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}')
    $unified=$(echo $line | awk '{print $4}')
    echo "eda pack --$Eda_package  wellbias is --$well_bias biasmap is --$biasmap  unified-      -- $unified"
    fi
    i=$((i+1))
    done < config.list
```

In the above bash program I get an error:

> ./script.sh: line 9: =EDA_7p0: command not found

How do I fix this?

Comment: Which of the lines is line 9?

Answer (score 5):

Lines of the form:

```
$xyzzy=plugh
```

will have `xyzzy` *substituted before they're executed* so that they look like:

```
=plugh
```

assuming they're not yet set. If they *are* set, you'll probably get different behaviour but still almost certainly not what you want.

You should change your lines from (for one example):

```
$Eda_package=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
```

to:

```
Eda_package=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
```

The `$` is not part of the variable name, it's an indication that the following word *is* a variable that should be substituted.

Answer (score 1):

Let var1=1 and var2=2 now if you simply write $var2=$var1 then it will give you error that 2=1 command not found

When you initialize any variable you have to do it without $ with variable name on left side